# Is it better practice for a React Dapp to a call a Smart Contract using Drizzle or Web3?

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, truffle, drizzle

For my React Dapp to call my smart contracts running on the ethereum block chain, is it better practice to use the Drizzle framework or call Web3 directly?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using drizzle because it will abstract some complexity and make your code more readable. Also check out [drizzle-react](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle-react) it provides some components and decorators that will be super useful.

However, be careful with this type of questions in SO, it might get downvoted, since it's kind of a subjective question and people  might have different opinions about it. This community is more about solving coding problems.

Best of luck.